# php foreach loop in a string

Tags: php, string, loops, foreach

i have a Problem with my foreach:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=center24', 'root', '');

$sql = "SELECT `Name`, `SP`, `NP`, `PP` FROM `mitarbeiter punkte`";


$string = '{
"cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Points","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Start Punkte","pattern":"","type":"number"},
    {"id":"","label":"Negative Punkte","pattern":"","type":"number"},
    {"id":"","label":"Positive Punkte","pattern":"","type":"number"}
  ],
"rows": [
    '.foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {.'
      {"c":[{"v":"'.$row['Name'];.'","f":null},{"v":'.$row['SP'];.',"f":null},{"v":-'.$row['NP'];.',"f":null},{"v":'.$row['PP'];.',"f":null}]},
    '.}.'  
  ]
}';

echo $string;
```

Comment: If it is json you are trying to build, you should look into `json_encode()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` doesn't return the output generated inside the loop, so you need to build up the string like this:

```
$string = '...';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $string .= '...';
}
```

That said, don't do that, and use `json_encode()` instead.